# To inherit or to override?

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance, composition, overriding

Imagine that I am writing a game where tanks fight with each other.

A generic **Tank** class is created and has the method *fire()* which fires a cannon, looks like this `Tank::fire() { /* fires a cannon */ }`

And then there is a class for **BossTank** which *fire()* fires a cannon and also a missile.

---

A senior advised me to do something like:

`Tank::fire() { fireProjectile(); }`, and create a new function:

`Tank::fireProjectile() { /* fire a cannon */ }`

Then in `BossTank` we can do inherit:

```
BossTank::fireProjectile() {
  parent::fireProjectile();
  /* fire a missile */
}
```

---

I don't know why, I do not feel good about this.  Maybe because the line `parent::fire()` looks inconsistent with more elementary lines for `/* fire a missile */`

Another coworker suggested this:

`Tank::fire() { fireCannon(); }` and `Tank::fireCannon() { /* fire a cannon */ }`

Then `BossTank::fire() { fireCannon(); fireMissile(); }` with `BossTank::fireMissile { /* fire a missile */ }` (this is a method only in this class)

---

I would like to go along these lines:

`Tank::fire() { fireCannon(); fireAdditionalProjectiles(); }` with `Tank::fireAdditionalProjectiles()` empty.

Then in `BossTank` we can override `fireAdditionalProjectiles()` to fire missiles.

---

So here are 3 ways to implement the "same" thing:

1. Senior: *Inheritance* - extracting fire cannon so no duplication.
2. Coworker: *Override* `fire()` and implement a new function only in **BossTank**
3. Me: Implement new function `fireCannon()` for no duplication, and `fireAdditionalProjectiles()` for overriding in **BossTank**

Is this a personal preference or there are standards regarding this situation?

Comment: This is still firing from the tank, but a tank HAVE waepon. Just need to think about some aggregation. This has the advantage to not need to inherit each time you need to define a new type of tank. See decorator pattern to add weapons to a tank easily.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a variety of tanks with different weapons, then it makes sense of compose your tank class

```
class Tank
{
    List<Weapon> weapons;
    void Fire()
    {
        foreach(var w in weapons) {w.Fire();}
    }
}
```

If all Tanks always have a Cannon, which always fires then overriding the Fire method and then calling the base class Fire plus some extras makes sense.

But I believe the current trend is towards composition, as people find that with multiple layers of inheritance the logic becomes too hard to follow.

For example, if you have a SuperBossTank which fires two missiles but no cannon you would have to introduce a new BaseTank with no weapon

Comment: I would unconditionally go with the list of weapons, even if all tanks have a cannon. No need for extra logic if you already have something generic in place.

Comment: its tricky because of the example, but you can imagine if it was Move() all tanks might have treads and boss tanks might have extra smoke that needs to come out of the exhaust